# How to automatically detect and fill a closed region using opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

All I have is the following bitmap:
[image: original contours image]
What I'm gonna do is to fill the contour automatically like the following:
[image: filled]
It's kind like the fill function in MS Painter. The initial contours will not cross the boundary of the image.

I don't have a good idea yet. Is there any method in OpenCV can do this? or any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be closed? Or could the input have a simple line for example? The latter would convert an easy problem into a much harder one

Comment: There is a [floodfill method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill) in opencv that works the same as the one in paint.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [Contours Hierarchy](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html) may help you to achieve this,

You need to do,

- Find every contours.
- Check hierarchy of each contour.
- Based on hierarchy draw each contour to new Mat with either thickness `filled` or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that regions have to be closed you can just scan horizontally and keep an edge count:

```
// Assume image is an CV_8UC1 with only black and white pixels.
uchar white(255);
uchar black(0);
cv::Mat output = image.clone();

for(int y = 0; y < image.rows; ++y)
{
    uchar* irow = image.ptr<uchar>(y)
    uchar* orow = output.ptr<uchar>(y)
    uchar previous = black;
    int filling = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < image.cols; ++x)
    {
       // if we are not filling, turn it on at a black to white transition
       if((filling == 0) && previous == black && irow[x] == white)
           ++filling ;

       // if we are filling, turn it off at a white to black transition
       if((filling != 0) && previous == white && irow[x] == black)
           --filling ;

       // write output image
       orow[x] = filling != 0 ? white : black;

       // update previous pixel
       previous = irow[x];
    }
}
```